# No tables found in odbc SQL Server connection using ActiveDirectoryInteractive Authentication using R

Tags: sql, r, azure-active-directory, odbc

When I create an odbc SQL Server connection in R using an `ActiveDirectoryInteractive` authentication method, I am prompted to enter my Microsoft credentials (as expected) and the connection is (presumably) successful but no tables are shown in the Connections tab.

Using the code below, I expected to establish an odbc connection through SQL Server where all the tables in the specified database would be visible in the Connections pane. Instead, the pane shows (No tables).

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(rstudioapi)

con3 <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                  Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                  Server = SQL_SERVER_NAME,
                  Database = SQL_DATABASE_NAME,
                  UID = rstudioapi::askForPassword(USERNAME),
                  Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryInteractive",
                  Port = PORT_NUM)
```

Answer (score 0):

I connected the Azure SQl server with active directory authentication by following below procedure:

I clicked on new connection in connections option in R studio

[image]

Selected ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server

[image]

Entered the connection string as mentioned below:

```
library(DBI) 
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<databasename>;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;", timeout = 10)
```

[image]

Click on Ok, it asked for authentication for the active directory, I entered username and password of active directory. And added fire wall rule as Ip address of R studio in Azure SQL database firewall settings.
It connected successfully.

[image]

In this way database and tables are visible, it worked for me kindly check from your end.